# Apache Camel Route doesn't set body

Tags: rest, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have two Apache Camel Routers in a Docker Network.

The one acts as client and sends some data in the body to the outer with a route.

I now want to get the modified body from the server router.

But apparently the body modification is never applied.

(For context the initial request is a post request where the final body should be the response)

Here is how my "client" route looks like:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

<restConfiguration component="restlet" bindingMode="json" port="8989" enableCORS="true"/>

<rest path="/finData">
  <description>User rest service</description>
  <post>
    <to uri="direct:update"/>
  </post>
</rest>

<route id="sendFinData">
  <from uri="direct:update"/>
  <log message="Got some data:  ${body}"/>
  <to uri="aclient://otherClient:9191"/>
</route>
```

And here is how the "server" looks like:

```
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">


 <route id="receiveFinData">
  <from
    uri="aserver://0.0.0.0:9191"/>
  <log message="Received via data: ${body}"/>
  <setBody>
    <simple>{"result": true }</simple>
  </setBody>
</route>
```

Update: If I add a second route to the "client" and call this one instead the external of the "server" and modify the body there it is working

Comment: what about <setBody><constant>...</constant></setBody> instead of <simple>?

Comment: Why would the simple version not work? Is it assuming a `$` in front of the `{...}`?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. For context: If I add a a route in the first "client" instance and modify the the body there it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update due to comments**: When the `setBody` is not the problem, then I have to ask about the flow in the code.

- Are you calling `/finData` to send a request from the client to the server?
- But who is listening on `aclient://otherClient:9191`? This route is not in your question.
- And the caller of `aserver://0.0.0.0:9191` is also not in your question.

Can you post the whole flow?

**Original answer**

I think @tadayoshi-sato already commented the solution to your problem.

You use the [Camel Simple language](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simple-language.html) (an Expression Language) to set a constant string into your message body.

Use the [Camel Constant language](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/constant-language.html) instead.

```
<setBody>
    <constant>{"result": true }</constant>
</setBody>
```

Comment: This does not seem to help

Comment: Then I have to ask about the flow in the code. Are you calling `/finData` to send a request from the client to the server? But who is listening on `aclient://otherClient:9191`? This route is not in your question. And the caller of `aserver://0.0.0.0:9191` is also not in your question. Can you post the whole flow?

Comment: you are right. My setup seems to be the problem. The way I do this is not supposed to work with the classical approach. I need to send data to the client and then update the body and send it to the app that invokes the call. Since your answer helped me I will accept it to close the question

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer. When your `setBody` works, the answer would be misleading